# Dropdown binding of database data inside a html table using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have to bind data using jquery to a dropdown that get created in a html table (row). I am not sure/clear is this situation is considered nested? I tried various ways but with no success. Below line of code is a sample that i tried.
way 1

```
$($($("#tbodyNewRow").children()[i]).children([0]).$("select[id*=selCompanyName]").val(RObject.ModelObject.mProperty);
```

Way2

```
$("#tblrow").$("select[id*=selCompName]").val(obj.value);
```

any link or sample is appreciated.

Comment: Please specify your query clearly, this question not able to understand what actually you're trying to achieve. If possible share sample code fiddler

Comment: @DaxeshVora, Thanks for response. I could achieve just now. but still lot of work to follow.

Comment: Now I am sure that this situation is of non-nested. Lot of thanks for  reading  my post.